# Glide to display image in listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I need help. I am trying to use glide to fetch my image from server but i do not know how?Please construct my code so that the Glide will work or give me any other possible solution. I just want to display image listview with Glide and JSON, the JSON result is from my PHP script.I am able to fetch other data out besides image. This is my code. Where the glide should I place?

```
 public class list extends ListActivity {

        private static final String TAG_POST= "posts";
        private static final String TAG_ID="lecID";
        private static final String TAG_NAME="lecName";
        private static final String TAG_EMAIL="lecEmail";
        private static final String TAG_PASS="lecPass";
        private static final String TAG_IMAGE="image";
        private static final String LECTURER_LIST_URL="http://system.com/list.php";

        private JSONArray mComments =null;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mcommentList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lec_Image);
//upload is the folder to store my image
            String leciv="http://fypesystem.com/upload/";
            Glide.with(this).load(leciv)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .into(imageView);
```

Your help really appreciated.

Comment: can you add your json response with question

Comment: You can not load folder URL into ImageView

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void LoadImage(Context cx,ImageView imageView,int demoImage,String url) {
    if (!((Activity) cx).isFinishing()){
        Glide.with(cx)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(demoImage)
                .into(imageView);
}
}
```

cx is context demoImage is image which shows until your image is load and Url is image path which you get from JSON.

Comment: Hi @Omer Hayat, where should i declare LoadImage() ?

Comment: This is method you can put it any class and use it or you can copy past it in your current activity or main activity and just call it when loading image just passing desire arguments.

Comment: But it shows error LoadImage(); cannot be applied. :(

Comment: Just remove static from it and try to call it like this LoadImage(this,imageView,R.drawable.demoImage,url)

Comment: ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId); where you want to show your server image

Comment: If i changed, there are error in cx,demoImage, Imageview
Glide.with(cx)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(demoImage)
                .into(imageView);

Comment: cx is context you have pass your activity context

Comment: change cx with this if your doing this in activity and if your are using fragment then use getActivity()

Comment: Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(demoImage)
                .into(imageView);

Answer (score 2):

You have to made a custom Adapter and pass that adapter a list you created from json and layout you want to use for adapter and a context of your activity .
And after that if you are using listview than in getView() function of listview add this code where url should be the value you stored in a list Like this

```
String url = mcommentList.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE);
```

`myImageView` should be the image from the layout you passed the adapter

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .into(myImageView);
```

you can check this link for help

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Change these line Specially the URL.

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lec_Image);
//upload is the folder to store my image
            String leciv="http://fypesystem.com/upload/9c419dd5659b0af4d14f642f454dcb07.jpg";
            Glide.with(this).load(leciv)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: if I write upload/9c419dd5659b0af4d14f642f454dcb07.jpg, it will just fetch the same image?

Comment: You have to got all the Url in an array list then set them one by one .   show me your json.